# main.py can't read function from module

Tags: python

I have a `main.py` and a module named `gui.py`

`main.py` contains

```
#some other imports#
import gui

if __name__ == '__main__':
    gui()
```

and in `gui.py` contains (the code is long so I only put the function which is the issue)

```
while True:
    (event, value) = window.read()
    if event ==  'Close'  or event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
        break # exit button clicked
    if event == 'like':
        def resource_path(relative_path):
            try:
                base_path = sys._MEIPASS
            except Exception:
                base_path = os.path.abspath(".")

            return os.path.join(base_path, relative_path)

        def find_regex_1(k, s):
            reg = f'{k}\s*=\s*(\S+)'
            return re.search(reg, s).group(1)

        def read_configs(config_file):
            with open(config_file, "r") as f:
                content = f.read()
                license_code = find_regex_1('LICENSE CODE', content)
                activation_code = find_regex_1('ACTIVATION CODE ', content)
            return license_code, activation_code

       if __name__ == '__main__':
            license_code, activation_code = read_configs('license.txt')

       def activate_license(license_key):
          machine_fingerprint = hashlib.sha256(str(get_mac()).encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()
          validation = requests.post(
            "https://api.example-url.com",
            headers={
                "Content-Type": "application/vnd.api+json",
                "Accept": "application/vnd.api+json"
            },
             data=json.dumps({
                "meta": {
                    "key": license_code,
                    "scope": {
                        "fingerprint": machine_fingerprint
                      }

                  }
              })
          ).json()
```

the `license.txt` is located in the root directory and when I run the `gui.py` module itself it will run without issues but when I run it through `main.py` it will give me an error:

```
  File "/Users/user1/Desktop/testing/main.py", line 24, in <module>
    import gui
  File "/Users/user1/Desktop/testing/gui.py", line 530, in <module>
    status, msg = activate_license(sys.argv[0])
  File "/Users/user1/Desktop/testing/gui.py", line 113, in activate_license
    "key": license_code,
NameError: name 'license_code' is not defined
```

already tried to add the root path in the `main.py` but no efforts

Comment: remove `if __name__ == '__main__':`, in gui.py when you are importing a module the `__name__` is not `__main__` anymore it is filename

Comment: `import gui` … `gui()` is also an issue.

Comment: in the gui.py? so what happens to the the `license_code, activation_code = read_configs('license.txt')`

Comment: i can remove the `gui()` in `main.py` but the issue remains

Comment: `if __name__ == '__main__':
            license_code, activation_code = read_configs('license.txt')` in gui.py conditionally defines `license_code`. What is the value of `__name__` when a module is called from another one?

Comment: @CatChMeIfUCan just remove the `if __name__ == '__main__':` line and indent `license_code, activation_code = read_configs('license.txt')` properly

Comment: tried this and worked  ` if __name__ == 'gui': license_code, activation_code = read_configs('license.txt')`

Comment: This is a bad practice, ` if name == 'gui'`, in future if you rename ur file, it won't work again, ideally, the initialization should not be under this clause. Why don't u understand the simple thing , just move that initialization from the clause!

Comment: but if i remove the if how can I define license_code, activation_code = read_configs('license.txt')

Comment: @CatChMeIfUCan check answer section

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move `license_code, activation_code = read_configs('license.txt')` from the `__name__` check

```py
.
.
.

        def read_configs(config_file):
            with open(config_file, "r") as f:
                content = f.read()
                license_code = find_regex_1('LICENSE CODE', content)
                activation_code = find_regex_1('ACTIVATION CODE ', content)
            return license_code, activation_code

       if __name__ == '__main__':
            pass

       license_code, activation_code = read_configs('license.txt')

       def activate_license(license_key):
          machine_fingerprint = hashlib.sha256(str(get_mac()).encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()
          validation = requests.post(
            "https://api.example-url.com",
            headers={
.
.
.
```

Comment: this looks like a better idea! so I don't need the if now! I can remove it, right?

Comment: Yes, you will put code under this __name__, when you want something to run when you are executing the file by itself, fo ex: some test etc.

Answer (score 1):

```
   if __name__ == '__main__':
        license_code, activation_code = read_configs('license.txt')
```

This means the code is executed only if the module is `__main__` which means it is launched directly.

When the module is called by another module (e.g. main.py), `__name__` is the name of the module itself (i.e. `gui`), not `__main__`.

Comment: ` if __name__ == 'gui':
            license_code, activation_code = read_configs('license.txt') ` is correct right? because is working now

Comment: I'd just remove whole condition. I don't know why you did this in the first place. To be honest, I didn't read all the code, I just stopped at that condition. It smells like design issue.

Answer (score 1):

This only works when you're calling that file as the main file, not when you're importing it:

```
 if __name__ == '__main__':
            license_code, activation_code = read_configs('license.txt')
```

Just remove the if statement and it should work.